# ask user to enter input such as their age and save it to a variable

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Im trying to make a simple bash script work as a beginner exercise
where im asking a user to enter their age and the script should echo depending on their input "You are old" or "you are young"
if they enter a number that is greater than or equal to 30 the prompt should echo "you are old" if they enter a number less than 30 it should echo "you are young"
it is as follows

```
#!bin/bash
myage=30
echo "Please enter your age"
read age
if [ $myage -ge 30 ];
then
echo "You are old"
else
echo "You are young"
fi
```

but the problem is that the script echoes the same line "You are old whether I input a number less than 30 or greater than, its as the else statement is being ignored.

what's the problem?

Comment: `$myage` and `$age` are two different unrelated variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will work for your purposes:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
myage=30
echo "Please enter your age"
read myage
if [ $myage -ge 30 ];
then
echo "You are old"
else
echo "You are young"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

"User input" cannot be trusted! What if the user enters "`I like cats`" or "`4t5`"? There are two conditions you must check: Is the answer a number; is the number "old". Do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# change this next birthday
myage=30
#
numok=0
while [[ 0 -eq $numok ]] ; do
    read -p "Enter your age: " age
    if [[ "$age" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
        numok=1
    else
        printf "Try again."
    fi
done
#
if [[ $age -ge $myage ]] ; then
    printf "You are old."
else
    printf "You are young."
fi
```

Note: this is untested; but checked via https://www.shellcheck.net/ for syntax.